# Restructuring table in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with a structure is like:

```
[["A","1","12"],
["A","2","112"],
["B","0","121"],
["B","1","21"],
["B","2","51"]]
```

I need to change it into a dataframe like:

```
   0  1  2
A  0  12 112
B 121 21 51
```

I tried the stack function, but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2)
df

1    0   1    2
0              
A  NaN  12  112
B  121  21   51
```

If you need to be cosmetically precise, use [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and [`rename_axis()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df.fillna(0).rename_axis(None, axis="index").rename_axis(None, axis="columns")

df
     0   1    2
A    0  12  112
B  121  21   51
```

Data:

```
data = [["A","1","12"],
        ["A","2","112"],
        ["B","0","121"],
        ["B","1","21"],
        ["B","2","51"]]
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(data).pivot(0,1,2).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)` Pandas version >0.24.0